# Search and filter with Spring Data Elasticsearch

Tags: java, spring, jpa, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have a JPA entity called `Invoice` with some properties and want to search and filter the results, but the filter is not working properly. I tried various combinations but no one worked for me.

This one correctly searches for instances having "foobar" in some of the properties:

```
// this is the search string...
String search = "foobar*";
QueryBuilder queryStringQuery = QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery(search);
NativeSearchQueryBuilder searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder();
searchQuery.withQuery(queryStringQuery);
// build and run against the ElasticsearchRepository
NativeSearchQuery query = searchQuery.build();
Page<T> result = searchRepository.search(query);
```

This is working and gives me all invoices, but now I only want to have "new invoices", which is given by a property called "state", which then has the value "New".

Currently, last one I tried is this one (according to similar questions on SO):

```
String search = "foobar*";
QueryBuilder queryStringQuery = QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery(search);
NativeSearchQueryBuilder searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder();
searchQuery.withQuery(queryStringQuery);

// add filter
QueryBuilder filters = QueryBuilders.termQuery("state", "New");
searchQuery.withFilter(searchFilters);

// build and run against the ElasticsearchRepository
NativeSearchQuery query = searchQuery.build();
Page<T> result = searchRepository.search(query);
```

This one gives me an empty result, although there must be some results.

I also tried to create somthing like this, but this is also not working:

```
String search = "foobar*";
QueryBuilder queryStringQuery = QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery(search);
searchFilters = QueryBuilders.termQuery("state", "New");

BoolQueryBuilder searchQuery = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().should(queryStringQuery).must(searchFilters);
Iterable<T> result = searchRepository.search(searchQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this

```
QueryBuilder qb;

QueryBuilder stateFilters = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
((BoolQueryBuilder) filters).filter(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("state", "New"));
qb = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().should(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery("foobar*")).filter(stateFilters );
```

the **filter** function here helps us with this

here **qb** will have the proper query which can now be used to search using the `elasticsearchRepository.search(qb)`;

Here is some information from spring docs:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.operations